# Selecting a region of an Image

Tags: java, image, user-interface

I need a method to select a rectangular region from an image (a `BufferedImage` into a `JLabel`).
When the user selects a region, I need to save the four points of the rectangle (pixel positions).

How to implement this using Java?
Is there a ready-to-use component?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To select a region of a `BufferedImage`, just do:

```
BufferedImage newImage = yourImage.getSubimage(x, y, width, height);
```

Adapt the code and provide the parameters `x`, `y`, `width` and `height` to define the rectangle.

**Important:** The new image will be **linked** to the original! If you update one, the other follows.

See the [Javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#getSubimage(int,%20int,%20int,%20int)) for more info.

---

**EDIT:** About the component that will allow the user to select the region, you can do a simple one yourself; or search a pre-made one in libraries like [SwingX](https://swingx.dev.java.net/), ...

If you choose to make a custom component, an approach will be: display the original image and ask the user to **click** on the **first** and **second** points of the rectangle to extract.

You can use a `MouseListener` to save the position of the user's clicks and pass these parameters to `getSubimage`. This would be an example:

```
public class RegionSelectorListener extends MouseAdapter {
    final JLabel label;

    public RegionSelectorListener(JLabel theLabel) {
        this.label = theLabel;
        theLabel.addMouseListener(this);
    }

    Point origin = null;

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent event) {
        if (origin == null) { //If the first corner is not set...

            origin = event.getPoint(); //set it.

        } else { //if the first corner is already set...

            //calculate width/height substracting from origin
            int width = event.getX() - origin.x;
            int height = event.getY() - origin.y;

            //output the results (replace this)
            System.out.println("Selected X is: "+ origin.x);
            System.out.println("Selected Y is: "+ origin.y);
            System.out.println("Selected width is: "+ width);
            System.out.println("Selected height is: "+ height);
        }
    }
}
```

To use it:

```
new RegionSelectorListener(yourlabel);
```

Comment: thanks for your help , i know how to do this step but what i need to know how to capture the rectangle points from user selection over the image (in the GUI)?

Comment: @radi see my edit. It should give you an idea. If you have any doubts, tell me!